# Share internet via notebook VPN through ad-hoc for other device;

Tags: windows-xp, vpn, ad-hoc-network

I'd like to make netbook work as ad-hoc and here's the problem: smartphone (i5700) connects to netbook via wifi, the internet (vpn) connection is shared with wifi connection but there's no internet on smartphone;
**Devices**:

1. Netbook -- acer D250-0BQk WinXP Home Edition SP3;
2. Apple ipod 4th gen iOS 5;
3. Samsung i5700 (2.2, custom kernel);

**"Topology"**:
The netbook is in local network and get internet connection via VPN;
Ipod or phone is connected to netbook via WIFI;

`ipconfig /all` on netbook:

```
IP Configuration for Windows

    The name of the computer. . . . . . . . . : ACERBOTTED
    The primary DNS-suffix. . . . . . :
    Node Type. . . . . . . . . . . . . : Unknown
    IP-routing is enabled. . . . : Yes
    WINS-proxy enabled. . . . . . . : No

Local Area Connection 2 - Ethernet adapter:

    DNS-Suffix. . : Beeline
    Description. . . . . . . . . . . . : Atheros AR8132 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller        
    Dhcp enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
    Autoconfiguration Enabled. . . . . : Yes
    IP-address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.89.76.1
    The subnet mask. . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.248.0
    Default Gateway. . . . . . . . . . : 10.89.72.1
    DHCP-server. . . . . . . . . . . : 78.107.63.213
    DNS-servers. . . . . . . . . . . : 85.21.192.3
                                        213.234.192.8
    Rent is received. . . . . . . . . : January 12, 2012 12:46:33
    Lease expires. . . . . . . . . : January 19, 2012 12:46:33

Wireless Connection - Ethernet adapter:

    DNS-Suffix. . :
    Description. . . . . . . . . . . . : Atheros AR5B95 Wireless Network Adapter
    Dhcp enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
    IP-address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
    The subnet mask. . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
    Default Gateway. . . . . . . . . . :
    DNS-servers. . . . . . . . . . . : 213.234.192.7
                                        85.21.192.3
                                        213.234.192.8
                                        195.14.50.1
                                        8.8.8.8
                                        127.0.0.1

beeline - PPP adapter:

    DNS-Suffix. . :
    Description. . . . . . . . . . . . : WAN (PPP / SLIP) Interface        
    Dhcp enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
    IP-address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 95.24.177.194
    The subnet mask. . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
    Default Gateway. . . . . . . . . . : 95.24.177.194
    DNS-servers. . . . . . . . . . . : 213.234.192.7
                                        195.14.50.1
```

The device (one of ipod or phone) successfully connects to netbook.
It get ip configs with DHCP (i also tried to input them staticly):
`ip: 192.168.0.2` 
`submask: 255.255.255.0` 
`gateway: 192.168.0.1` 
`dns: 192.168.0.1` 

I can ping `192.168.0.2` and `192.168.0.1` from netbook but i cannot ping `192.168.0.1` from connected through wifi device (e.g. phone); It looks like one way traffic tunnel;
The firewalls are disabled (windows' and nod's);

Any suggestions what's wrong?

Comment: A few questions. Are you using a VPN on your wired network connection? Why is 127.0.0.1 (loopback) listed as a DNS server in the config?

Comment: Yes, it's shared with ICS on wired network. 
That's just for a test;

Comment: Yes, but are you specifically using a Virtual Private Network?

Comment: VPN is just connected on netbook that's in local network and shared so that wireless device may use it for its purpose; I don't connect to VPN at the smartphone.

Comment: As topic is about ICS and inactive i'll mark billc.cn's answer as correct, still it hasn't fixed the problem; And as everything now is working with bridge conception i'd to like ask someone to upvote laurent's answer for i've made some progress with his help (inet works on wireless device, still it is not shared);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you used ICS, did you set it up from the VPN's properties or your PPPoE connection's? You should always do it from the "logical" connection that should be shared (i.e. the VPN) instead of the "physical" connection it runs on.

Several other things to consider:

- ICS may not be working until the VPN is connected, so don't connect any WIFI clients until the VPN is on.
- You should not use the network bridge feature as it works at a totally different stack layer and cannot be used for VPN sharing generally. (What you need here is to share one line and one IP to multiple computers, which is NAT which is what ICS does.)
- ICS also functions as a DHCP server and DNS server, so it will setup the "shared to" interface (i.e. your wireless card) to the 192.168.x.1 IP and send out DHCP packets that sets it as the default gateway and DNS.

  - Due to this, you should change the settings of the "shared to" interface after ICS has been setup. If you did, you'll have to disable ICS and setup it up again.
  - I don't think the default IP subnet is 192.168.0.1, did you change that?
- You may need to configure your firewall for the NAT router and DNS server to work.
- Your VPN provider may be preventing ICS by checking the TTL of the packets, in which case ICS can't be used.

Comment: 1. I've just tried to connect to VPN after the wireless device is connected to netbook -- the internet still doesn't work on that wireless device;<br />
2. Bridge was deleted, new ICS connection configured;<br />
3.1. The ICS sets up ip to 192.168.0.1 and submask to 255.255.255.0, and gateway to empty in windows xp by default. If this's incorrect what should i changed it for?
3.2. No, i didn't, It is set by default;
4. All firewalls were disabled besides nod firewall is in study mode that is allowing everything is happenning in network;
5. How can that be checked?

Comment: About the first paragraph: i used ICS direct on the vpn connection properties. That vpn connection is used to get access to internet;

Answer (score 0):

obs: Netbook not answering ping does not always mean that the connection is not established because windows machine often do not answer ping as the firewall can block it.

Not sure if this is the unique problem but how can your smartphone get 192.168.0.2 IP if DHCP in wifi adapter on netbook is OFF? Or is it an old config?
You should turn it on and let it send default gateway and DNS relay to the smartphone's subnet for it to connect to internet.

Why don't you only bridge your LAN 2 (ethernet card) with Wifi adapter on netbook and it will do the job like if the smartphone were in the working LAN?

Comment: Pretty interesting question, haven't even been thinking about it. The wifi connection on netbook is set to that's now so that it can work as ad-hoc. The wireless network is created(without pass and encryption, name i.e. `adhoc`) and netbook connects to `adhoc` and waits for device to be connected. As device is connected it's also given an IP adress an other by DHCP. In my post i meant:
- the ip can be given either by DHCP or inputted manually. The internet doesn't work anyway.
Will try a bridge connection now;
Sorry for my English;

Comment: If i make a brigde connection the ip given by DHCP to the phone is `10.89.79.158`; If bridge ip is changed to `192.168.0.1` and others respectively the VPN returns and error as it cannot connect;

Comment: The situation so far: the bridge is made. Ipod or smart can connect to netbook via wifi and authorisize on VPN connection; Internet works on ipod|smart; The problem: VPN cannot be connect at same time on the netbook and other devices, it gets error #691; The same old question. How can i share VPN connection with inet on netbook with wireless (connected to this netbook) device? Thanks